# SQL 1 Digit Before The Decimal Place

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm storing a ratio of a total in a table and therefore know I'll only have values between 0 and 1, and 4 decimal places are sufficient precision. Therefore I've created the table column as `DECIMAL(5,4)`.

When calculating the data for population I have found a strange behaviour where SQL seems to want an extra 2 places before the decimal, so if I use `DECIMAL(5,4)` or `DECIMAL(6,4)` I get an `Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.` error. I have to push it to `DECIMAL(7,4)` for one side of the divide, then wrap the whole divide in another cast to get the precision I actually require.

SQL considers every different precision a different datatype, invoking a conversion, so I'm conscious of the workload this is adding when done at scale as I can't cast straight to the `DECIMAL(5,4)` I'm storing it as. I'm also just curious as to what is happening to cause this.

The example below demonstrates the issue. It should work with `DECIMAL(2,1)`, but it will only work with `DECIMAL(3,1)`. Even then, the results are to 6 decimal places. Can anyone at least explain what's happening here, and hopefully a way to avoid it without doubling up on casts?

```
DECLARE @SalesTable TABLE (ProductId INT, Size NVARCHAR(2), Quantity INT)
INSERT INTO @SalesTable VALUES (123, 'S', 5), (123, 'M', 20), (123, 'L', 15), (123, 'XL', 10)

SELECT Size, sales.Quantity / CAST(sales.Total AS DECIMAL(3,1)) AS SalesRatio
FROM (
    SELECT Size, Quantity, SUM([Quantity]) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId) AS Total
    FROM @SalesTable
) AS sales
```

uses an extra decimal and produces a result to a different precision

```
Size    SalesRatio
S       0.100000
M       0.400000
L       0.300000
XL      0.200000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your confusion.  In your example, `salesTotal1` has a value of `50`.  This requires two digits to the left of the decimal place.

Perhaps the confusion is on internal types for decimals.  Although the rules are complicated for multiplication and very, very arcane for division, the rules are much simpler for addition:  the type doesn't change.

So, the total needs to fit in the decimal value.

If you care about the type of the *result* of an arithmetic operation, then convert the entire expression:

```
SELECT Size,
       CAST(sales.Quantity * 1.0 / sales.Total AS DECIMAL(3,1)) AS SalesRatio
```

The `* 1.0` may not be necessary, but it makes sure that the division has decimal places.

Comment: The `* 1.0` is absolutely needed, and what I was missing to do it in 1 shot. I didn't see my mistake on converting a larger component down in my real code, and then failed to see it again when I created the simple example. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The decimal precision should be set to the maximum length needed to contain the largest number included in the calculation (unless otherwise dealt with).  In this case Quantity is data type INT which has min/max of -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647).  To be covered in all situations you could make the data type Decimal(16, 4).  12 digits for any integer + 4 places to the right of the decimal point.  SQL Server with automatically expand the decimal precision if you add or multiply 1.0 to the denominator of a quotient.  Something like this

```
DECLARE @SalesTable TABLE (ProductId INT, Size NVARCHAR(2), Quantity INT)
INSERT INTO @SalesTable VALUES (123, 'S', 5), (123, 'M', 20), (123, 'L', 15), (123, 'XL', 10)

SELECT Size, cast(sales.Quantity / (sales.Total*1.0) AS DECIMAL(16,4)) AS SalesRatio
FROM (
    SELECT Size, Quantity, SUM([Quantity]) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId) AS Total
    FROM @SalesTable
) AS sales;
```

Output

```
Size    SalesRatio
S       0.1000
M       0.4000
L       0.3000
XL      0.2000
```